# Function<T, R> Object in Java with no specified parameters as input and Double as output

Tags: java, function

I've made a Matrix class in java and I wanted to add some `init()` functions.
I need one that takes as the first argument a `Function` object, and the function's arguments if needed as the second.
I have encountered two problems:\

- If the function only takes one argument, the notation `init(Function<> func, Object... args)` gives an error is thrown when compiling: `incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int`.
- If I work around that (by calling `init(FuncClass::Func, 7, null)`, which doesn't seem such a good idea), I have an error thrown at `func.apply(args)` because `incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int`.

The current function definition is this:

```java
public void init(Function<Object, Double> function, Object... args){
    for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            this.data[i][j] = function.apply(args);
        }
    }
}
```

The `data` object is defined as:
`double[][] data = new double[rows][cols];`

Edit: since it came up in the comments, I noticed that the title can be misunderstood.
The problem isn't no input at all. It shouldn't have a predetermined input. I mean, it could be defined as `func()` as well as `func(double min, double max, Random rn, double seed)`.
If you can suggest a more explanative title, please do.

Comment: If we want no input and some output, we can use a lambda of type [`Supplier` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Comment: The problem isn't no input at all. It shouldn't have a predetermined input. I mean, it could be defined as `func()` as well as `func(double min, double max, Random rn, double seed)`.

Comment: Can you paste you function because I think you trying to do some integer operations on Object Type which cant be possible because Object class is broader than Integer.

Comment: The function is just a test function I made up it's declared as `public static double goodFunc(int goodNum){ return (double) goodNum-1; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that:

- The interface `Function<T, R>` is specifically designed for a 1-input 1-output function.
- In the parent package (`java.util.function`) there is no interface for a function that takes more than 1 argument. (Edit: as pointed in the comments, there also are interfaces that take two arguments. Still, that doesn't solve my problem.)

The solution might be to force the function given as parameter to accept an array of objects as the only argument, then parse them as required.

An example of this would be something like:

```java
public static double func(Object[] args){
  int a = (int) args[0];
  int b = (int) args[1];
  return (double) a * b;
}
```

(The parsing isn't done in a try-catch block because I want an exception thrown anyway if the wrong args are given to the function)

Comment: “In the parent package (java.util.function) there is no interface for a function that takes more than 1 argument.”  Except for all the interfaces with a `Bi` syllable in their names (BiFunction, BiConsumer, BiPredicate, ToIntBiFunction, ToLongBiFunction, ToDoubleBiFunction), the interfaces with `Binary` in their names (BinaryOperator, IntBinaryOperator, LongBinaryOperator, DoubleBinaryOperator), and every interface starting with `Obj` (ObjIntConsumer, ObjLongConsumer, ObjDoubleConsumer).

Comment: You're right. Those interfaces take two arguments. The problem is still the same: I don't wanna pass a function that takes only one argument, nor one that takes two. I don't know how many arguments it'll take. I was looking for something much more flexible